# Map Multiple Tables to One Table Produces Foreign Key Column for each in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to Point 3 tables Property, Business, Automobile to single Table named Utility.
Using Fluent NHibernate, I followed

```
    public UtilityMap()
    {
        // some Mappings
        References<Automobile>(x => x.Automobile, "LeaseRefId").Cascade.None();
        References<Business>(x => x.Business, "LeaseRefId").Cascade.None();
        References<Property>(x => x.Property, "LeaseRefId").Cascade.None();
    }
```

and in Each table that maps to the Utility, I followed

```
    public AutomobileMap()
    {
        //Some Mappings

        HasOne<Utility>(x => x.CommonDatas)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
```

**"I want to have a single column in Utility Table that can store the
  references of all the three (Automobile, Business, Property) tables.
  But fluent Nhibernate is creating foreing key columns for each of the
  table referenced. I want to avoid this."**

Is there any way to achieve this??
Please suggest
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work as you expect, you'll need to have a base class for `Automobile`, `Business` and `Property` classes. Let's call it `LeaseSubject`. Presumably, you already have something like that in your domain model.

Your Utility class should have only one property, instead of three you have now:

```
public virtual LeaseSubject LeaseSubject { get; set; }
```

This way you not only have easier mapping, but also promote the maintainability of your code. What if at some later time you decide to have one more lease subject, i.e. `Yacht`? Instead of adding another `Yacht` property to your Utility class, you just need to inherit from `LeaseSubject`, and it could be contained within the `LeaseSubject` property on `Utility` class.

Now you could map your Utility simply as:

```
public UtilityMap() 
{
    // Other mappings...
    References(x => x.LeaseSubject, "LeaseRefId");
}
```

For mapping Automobile, Business and Property classes, you would use one of three available NHibernate [inheritance strategies](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-strategies):

- table per class hierarchy
- table per subclass
- table per concrete class

For [FluentNHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) inheritance mapping, take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat).

Since you already have separate tables, I believe the correct strategy for your case would be Table per concrete class. You can find some more info in this [article](http://ang3lfir3.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/table-per-clas%E2%80%A6ent-nhibernate/).